# spacy updating NER

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

Spacy [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/training#ner) shows how to update an NER with additional training examples. However, it trains using the entities offsets. How can I perform the same task but using **BILUO scheme**? I want to use training examples that contain for each sentence the list of tokens and the respective **BILUO tags**.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question. 
From the [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/training#ner):

> The spacy.gold module also exposes two helper functions to convert offsets to BILUO tags, and BILUO tags to entity offsets.

So, it will go like this:

```
from spacy.gold import offsets_from_biluo_tags
doc = nlp('I like London.')
tags = ['O', 'O', 'U-LOC', 'O']
entities = offsets_from_biluo_tags(doc, tags)
```

Using the entities variable for each sentence create the TRAIN_DATA list and proceed with the code in the documentation.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I end up using [convert](https://spacy.io/api/cli#convert) command to convert my gold file to json and then load it with [GoldCorpus](https://spacy.io/api/goldcorpus). But thanks anyway.